# Can I use my old SSD with a new laptop?

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-11

Can I reuse my old SSD with a new Windows laptop assuming it's the only drive and the system drive and both are PCIe NVMe M.2 SSDs? I.e. remove the original SSD in my new notebook and build-in the old one? For example because my old SSD is bigger than the new one and/or I don't want to reinstall all apps and transfer all my data?

Comment: yes you can probably use the disk, if the key type matches, etc, but no you probably cannot use the operating system and applications from the other laptop. even if it boots, it will probably always be not-quite-right.

Comment: As @FrankThomas states, you may need to re-register Windows, installed on the old SSD, with Microsoft... which might not be possible. Some apps require installation, while many are portable and do not. An alternative is to put the old SSD in an enclosure and use it as an additional drive. Portable apps, such as Notepad++,  can run from that drive, though you'll need to set file associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done exactly this many, many times. Here are some things you should know:

- This should be obvious, but the architectures of the two laptops need to match.
- You will probably need to manually install some drivers from the manufacturer. If you don't have easy access to another computer, pre-download the network drivers in case you need those.
- Anything that relies on the TPM will need to be reconfigured. So if your drive is bitlocker encrypted, be sure to disable it first. Also, if you're joined to an Azure AD domain, you will need to leave and rejoin.
- If copying to a new disk (assuming you're using GPT), you will need to run bcdboot (i.e from a Windows installer) to update the Windows bootloader with the new partition IDs.

The point is, it's certainly doable, albeit probably with some hassle. In my opinion, if you'd rather have your old system than a fresh, clean installation, it's probably worth the trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed experience report. Sounds even worse than re-installing all apps. One could do the math how many man-lifes on earth Microsoft could save us all with a solution to this PC migration issue.

Comment: How about Bitlocker and Windows File History & Backup and Restore: must PC and backup-medium match Bitlocker-wise or do we get to choose any combination?

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to install your old SSD, because :

- Windows will become unregistered because of the big hardware change,
  but probably will re-enable itself by digital entitlement, so that won't be
  a big problem.
- You will have in Windows the drivers to the hardware components from
  the old Windows installation. Windows will update most drivers, but some
  may require downloading drivers from the manufacturer(s) of the
  new computer. Better download these drivers in advance, because the
  network card might be one of the devices that won't work.
- Useful utilities installed by the manufacturer of the new computer
  will be missing from the old SSD. Some you may be able to download
  from the website of the manufacturer.
- You should verify the SMART attributes of the old disk to check that
  it's in good shape and has a long enough lifetime left.
  There is no guarantee that this estimate will be correct.
  The old SSD will certainly fail much before the new one.
  You may use an application such as
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).

My advice is to bite the bullet and install your old apps on the new
computer and transfer your data. You may install the old SSD in the
new computer as a second disk, or inside an enclosure.

Comment: you can also rescue a lot of your applications configurations by selectively copying dirs/files from your users %appdata% from the prior install to the new system. don't just copy everything, but if you do it just for the apps you know you have configuration you want to preserve, it makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @Frank Thomas Ok, thanks. And what if instead I just want to replace my new laptop's SSD against a bigger other NEW SSD? Could I simply insert the other, new SSD into the new notebook or would I still have to clone the original SSD onto the other, new SSD which I plan to replace it with before?

Comment: do you have OEM installation media for the new laptop? if so I'd use a new disk, and install windows on it that way, but yes you would have to get an OS on the new disk, so be it by installing, or cloning, that is necessary.